# How to remove antd donut chart hover and select effect

Tags: reactjs, charts, components, antd, donut-chart

In the donut chart in @ant-design/plots,

1. There is a black border around the individual sections of the donut chart when hovered.
2. The individual section is translated away from the center when selected.

How to stop/ control these behavior?

[image]

```
const config = {
    appendPadding: 10,
    data,
    angleField: 'value',
    colorField: 'type',
    radius: 1,
    innerRadius: 0.6,
    label: {
      type: 'inner',
      offset: '-50%',
      content: '{value}',
      style: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 14,
      },
    },
    interactions: [
      {
        type: 'element-selected',
      },
      {
        type: 'element-active',
      },
    ],
    statistic: {
      title: false,
      content: {
        style: {
          whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap',
          overflow: 'hidden',
          textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
        },
        content: 'AntV\nG2Plot',
      },
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

### Deal with interactions in config

> 1. There is a black border around the individual sections of the donut chart when hovered.

Remove the object `type:'element-active'`

Note: Removing is conveyed by commenting out in the code below.

```
 interactions: [
      ...
      // {
      //  type: 'element-active',
      // },
    ]
```

> 2. The individual section is translated away from the center when selected.

Remove the object `type: 'element-selected'`

Note: Removing is conveyed by commenting out in the code below.

```
 interactions: [
      ...
      // {
      //  type: 'element-selected',
      // },
    ]
```

To achieve both you can simply remove the `interactions` from the config object.